# Do extraordinary and ordinary waves combine after passing through plasma?

Tags: classical-electrodynamics, plasma-physics

If linearly polarized wave is passing through plasma in a parallel way with a magnetic field in plasma, it splits in two waves, right and left circularly polarized. Subsequently, the waves are combined together to linearly polarized wave in vacuum (also we consider Faraday rotation). However, extraordinary and ordinary wave are passing through plasma in a perpendicular way to a magnetic field. What happens with them after that in vacuum? I would say that they propagate independently.

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking.  Are you worried about the superposition/interference of the waves?  If in a plasma, those two modes propagate at different phase speeds so would not stay in phase (i.e., if left- and right-hand polarized, they would not create a time-independent linearly polarization).  As for their exiting a plasma into a vacuum, just take the limit as $\Omega_{cs}$ and $\omega_{ps}$ go to zero (since vacuums have neither fields nor particles).

Comment: The wave propagates through a vacuum, then it propagates through a plasma and splits into two modes, as we said. The thing I am confused about is if they propagate as two independent waves (according to vacuum dispersion relation of course) in a vacuum after exiting a plasma. Because (in a parallel way to a magnetic field), left and right circularly polarized waves create linear polarization again after exiting, just rotation of the plane of polarization appears.

Comment: You assume they stay in phase before, during, and after the region with a plasma?  That is not true, as the phase velocity is different for the two modes you suggest.  So unless they occupy all space, the result will be more complicated.

Comment: I assume that they are in phase before, not in phase during and not in phase after and I am asking if it is right that they do NOT stay in phase AFTER (because that is how I understand it). (I am sorry that my explanations are not clear enough.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A linearly polarized wave with vertical incidence (direction z)  in the plasmafrom vacuum on a plasma slab with polarization angle phi relative to a magnetic field B parallel to the slab can be considered to split in the plasma into two linearly polarized waves with different phase velocities and amplitudes. One with a polarization parallel and one with a polarization vertical to the magnetic field. Because of this, the phase difference of the waves changes along z in the plasma producing an elliptical polarization of the composite wave which changes direction and ellipticity along z. Finally, in general, an elliptically polarized wave exits the slab with constant ellipticity and polarization. A detailed discussion would involve external and internal reflections, which however would not change the qualitative outcome.

Comment: So, if I understand it right, does an elliptically polarized wave exit the slab with constant ellipticity and also a linearly polarized (polarization parallel to the magnetic field in the slab) wave exit the slab with constant linear polarization?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: Any incident linearly polarized wave exits, in general, as an elliptically polarized wave with constant polarization and ellipticity. If the incident linear polarization is either parallel or vertical to the magnetic field the light also exits as a linearly polarized wave parallel or vertical to the magnetic field, respectively

Comment: It is more clear now. I was little bit confused because of Faraday effect of two circularly polarised waves. It made me think of what happens with ordinary and extraordinary wave.

Comment: In describing the Faraday effect the magnetic field B is parallel to the incident linearly polarized wave. This can be decomposed into a left and a right polarized wave, which have different phase velocities in the plasma so that the composite wave in the plasma is linearly polarized with the polarization changing along the propagation direction. The exiting wave is linearly polarized with a changed polarization angle.

Comment: However  if the magnetic field B is perpendicular to the wave, ordinary and extraordinary wave can propagate in different directions. Is there really only composite elliptically polarized wave exiting? (I imagine it as analogy with extraordinary and ordinary rays in calcite)

Comment: There is an analogy with the birefrigence of calcite. There the different propagation directions of ordinary and extraordinary wave only appear when the direction of the incident wave is not normal to the optical axis, which is usually not parallel to the surface of the crystal. In the case of the plasma slab with in-plane magnetic field B and normal incident wave,  both the ordinary and the extraordinary wave propagate in the same direction normal both to B and to the slab surfaces and exit the slab perpendicular to the surface producing in combination an elliptically polarized wave.